# Output div id data into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got this div id with html data, how can i output that html data into a javascript variable? example
`var url = '(HtmlDivId)';` is this possible?

Comment: The div with the urls is <div id="links"> i want to out put the urls in an variable as  `var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';` i have tried this `var url ='<div id="links">';` but didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you are trying to read content of the div?

```
//jQuery
var url = $('#HtmlDivId').html();

//javascript
var url = document.getElementById('HtmlDivId').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Yes, i want to output the url inside `var url = "link from div id";`@Radek Pech

Comment: So your HTML is e.g. <div id="HtmlDivId">google.com</div> ? Then this is what you need.

Comment: i want the url from the div id `<div id="links">` to output like this `var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';`

Comment: tired it again and it worked! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure

```
var url = document.getElementById('html-div-id').innerHTML;
```